# If I started a service with "sudo start service_name" how do I check (later) if it's running?

Tags: linux, service, upstart

I've started an upstart service using the command `sudo start myservice`. I want a way so that later, I (or anyone) can check if the service is up and running. What would the command be to check that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer:

```
sudo initctl list | grep servicename
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply:

```
service myservice status
```

If you wanna see *all* the services use:

```
service --status-all
```

Edit: After seeing that it doesn't work for upstart, try using `initctl list`.

Comment: This doesn't work for upstart. I just get: "servicename unrecognized service"

Comment: Ugh I actually JUST got the right one and you also answered lol